# Which is a better expression between "as you wish" and "I don't care" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, phrase-choice

I'm now translating a cartoon to English, and I can't choose which expression I should use here, cause I don't exactly know the difference between them.

The scene is like the following:

> W: Aren't you going?
>
> M: Huh? Thi-this early?
>
> M: Ca-can i stay a little longer?
>
> W: ...
>
> **As you wish./ I don't care (what you do).**

Here, this woman is saying "if you want to." or "do whatever you want". And she isn't that nice and friendly woman. She's kind of acting a little cold.

Then which is a better choice between "as you wish" and "I don't care what you do" here?

Or is better to say just "if you want to."?

Comment: _As you wish_ seems a bit friendly, in the light of your explanation. Another option would be _suit yourself_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person is cold and indifferent, a proper response might be, "Whatever.."

But if I had to pick between the ones you mentioned, I think "Do whatever you want" is best amongst these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I googled "Whatever" and it says it is used "as a response indicating a reluctance to discuss something, implying indifference, skepticism, or exasperation." But here, the woman is actually "allowing" him to "do what he want", not just "expressing a reluctance." Can I still use "Whatever" in this context? So does "whatever" actually mean "(Do) whatever (you want)?"

Comment: @dbwlsld You can also use "Whatever" as an answer to a question you don't want to delve into, and I think that's the definition that you found.  "Whatever" here means "Do what you prefer" without sounding particularly interested one way or the other.  Actually saying "Do whatever you want" sounds less cold if only because you're bothering to say the entire phrase.  I assume you want her to show indifference, so I would still suggest "Whatever."

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, through gritted teeth and with a sigh: "If you must". That would give the impression that that W is not happy about M staying longer than W was expecting or hoping for.